# Setting up root domain as link

Tags: dns, branch.io, nameservers

I'm trying to set up my root domain as my link in the link settings form.
when I put it I get this warning.

> Domain is incorrectly set up; please use the nameservers below as your
>   NS record. A CNAME record is not required. If you've already done
>   this, note that it can take up to several hours to propagate.
>
> - ns-907.awsdns-49.net.
> - ns-1438.awsdns-51.org.
> - ns-1683.awsdns-18.co.uk.
> - ns-401.awsdns-50.com.

So I changed my ns in goddady to those
[image: godaddy dns config]

now if I run `$ host -t NS getgogro.com` I get 2 different outputs randomly

[image: host -t NS output]

> - getgogro.com name server ns64.domaincontrol.com.
> - getgogro.com name server ns63.domaincontrol.com.

I believe this 2 are still godaddy's default dns, but I dont always get that output

and http://getgogro.com/ already takes me to branch.io

but in the Link Settings section I sell get the same warning

> Domain is incorrectly set up; please use the nameservers below as your
>   NS record. A CNAME record is not required. If you've already done
>   this, note that it can take up to several hours to propagate.
>
> - ns-907.awsdns-49.net.
> - ns-1438.awsdns-51.org.
> - ns-1683.awsdns-18.co.uk.
> - ns-401.awsdns-50.com.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching out to Branch. Let me follow up with you directly via email!